# How to change format of a number in sql?

Tags: php, mysql, format

I have a MySQL table with hours:

```
10:30
11:00
9:00
```

how to format the numbers in PHP output and order them ASC?

I suppose, I need to change the format of the numbers to something like this?

```
09:00
10:30
11:00
```

Comment: Do you want the format to be changed in PHP os SQL?

Comment: The best way is to store minutes and hours in 2 columns, then you will be able to order (ORDER BY hour, minute ASC)

Comment: You'll need the date function in PHP.... True Story.

Comment: @putvande I need to change the format in PHP as I can not alter the database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$times_array = array();
$times = array("10:30","11:00","9:00");
foreach($times as $time){
    $times_array[strtotime($time)] = $time;
}

ksort($times_array);
print_r($times_array);
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you should change your field type for a "time" format. For ordering it's the best

Answer (score 0):

Here's an idea...

Store the time (PHP time() function), that way you'll be able to do whatever you want easily.

```
$strTime = time();
INSERT INTO tablename (time) VALUES ('$time');
```

Then you'll be able to sort easily...

```
// For example - simple query
SELECT time FROM table ORDER BY time ASC
```

or

```
SELECT HOUR(time), MINUTE(time) FROM table ORDER BY HOUR(time), MINUTE(TIME) ASC;
```

Displaying in PHP...

```
$strTimeFromDB = $arrDBResult['time'];

// Displaying the time e.g.: 11:00
echo date("H:i", $strTimeFromDB);
```